# How to retain matsortdirection in angular when switching tabs?

Tags: angular

i have tried to store matSortDirection in local storage but on retrieving it gives error as
'String' is not assignable to type 'SortDirection':

```
public sortData(sort: Sort)
{

  localStorage.setItem('xyz', sort.active)
  localStorage.setItem('abc', sort.direction)
}

let PGDirection:string= String(localStorage.getItem('abc'))


        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(sourceName);
        this.dataSourceLength = sourceName.length;
        this.sort.active = PGActive;
        this.sort.direction=PGDirection;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message basically tells you the whole story.

`sort.direction` appears to have the type SortDirection. LocalStorage can only store string.

When you are using `localStorage.setItem('abc', sort.direction)` it tries to convert `sort.direction` into a string. You should do that manually: `JSON.stringify(sort.direction)`.

Now when you are retrieving this from localStorage you will need to turn this back into an SortDirection object. Something like `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('abc'))`.

So your code should look something like this:

```
public sortData(sort: Sort) {
  localStorage.setItem('xyz', JSON.stringify(sort.active))
  localStorage.setItem('abc', JSON.stringify(sort.direction))
}

let PGDirection: SortDirection = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('abc'))

this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(sourceName);
this.dataSourceLength = sourceName.length;
this.sort.active = PGActive;
this.sort.direction=PGDirection;
```

Not sure whether SortDirection is an interface or a class. If it is a class, you might need to call it's constructor after retrieving the data from localStorage.

Comment: Hi tommueller thanx for the reply. I did as you you mentioned but am still getting the same error. :/

Comment: Thanx i tried this. Now, it throws same error on PGDirection. :/

Comment: Ok, I gave this another rewrite ;)

Comment: thnx a ton man. For the knowledge and help. :) It works like a charm.